# Configure Hangfire serialization to handle polymorphic arguments?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

I'm trying to adapt Hangfire to match different paradigm using polymorphic messages with single handler. 
Let me give some pseudo-code:

```
public class Message {}
public class MessageA: Message { public string FieldA: int }
public class MessageB: Message { public string FieldB: int }

class Handler {
   public void Execute(message: Message);
}

BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Handler>(h => h.Execute(new MessageB()));
```

It seems like Hangfire is deserializing `MessageB` as `Message` because this is a declared type in `Handler.Execute`.

Can I setup Hangfire to include actual type information?
I managed to this somehow by messing with JsonSerializer settings but I broke serialization in some other parts of the system. 
Can argument serialization options be configured separately?
Hangfire stores assembly version

Comment: `{ public string FieldA: int }`? How did I do that? :-)

Comment: Have you tried `Hangfire.Common.JobHelper.SetSerializerSettings()`?

Comment: @AlexSkalozub Thanks, it seems like an option but in such case the only working solution is `TypeNameHandling.All` as `Auto` doesn'tt work for top level object. On top of that `TypeNameHandling.All` blows the serialized size out of proportion. `JobHelper.SetSerializerSettings()` also affects how Hangfire serializes it's own stuff. Anyway, it's a step in right direction (although using static class smells) but not a complete solution.

Comment: you can also create a custom `JsonConverter` for your `Message` class.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub Yep. Currently I'm trying `Envelope` with custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: I've got this working by using the following: `Hangfire.Common.JobHelper.SetSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings{ TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });` This, I believe, adds the type of the object in the json (under the field `$type`), that way Hangfire will afterwards have access to the right type, once invoking the enqueued method. HTH someone.

Comment: One thing I must add though- it's a shame this cannot be done through the call to `services.AddHangfire(configure=> /*configure hangfire...*/);` like with `configure.SetSerializerSettings(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Hangfire allows serialization setup with:

```
options.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings());
```